# Objective c keyboardType not change

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

i am try to change my input filed keyboard type for that i am using `[redeemCode setKeyboardType:UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad];` this

```
- (void)keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification*)aNotification

    {
        [redeemCode isFirstResponder];
        [redeemCode setKeyboardType:UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad];
    }
```

when i am failed to change keyboard type that time ,i used  `redeemCode.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumbersAndPunctuation;` but i am failed .

```
  - (void)keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification*)aNotification
    {
        [redeemCode becomeFirstResponder];
        redeemCode.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumbersAndPunctuation;
    }
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that U set the type after the keyboard was already shown. 
Define the appropriate keyboard type somewhere earlier in your code.
Like:

```
UITextField *tf = //textfield allocation
tf.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumbersAndPunctuation;
......
[tf becomeFirstResponder];
```

Comment: In such case make sure that this property is not redefined somewhere else in your code. Or try to set it in UIKeyboardWillShowNotification observer's handler

Answer (score 0):

Move the following line

```
   redeemCode.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad;
```

to your `viewDidLoad` and remove the other 2 methods

Also check that redeemCode isn't `nil` and if its an outlet you've set up it should probably be `self.redeemCode`

Comment: i done it .  redeemCode.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad; where i alloc redeemCode